# What is the best way to develop a fully featured android chat application?

Tags: android, socket.io, chat

I know couple of things like socket.io is a library which can be used to develop a chat application but apart from this what else is required?
What technologies are required to build a fully featured android chat app?
What is alternative of Socket.io for an android app?

Comment: You can develope chat application even using google firebase simply..follow this link:https://github.com/imaimiami/react-native-firebase-chat-demo                          https://github.com/thaleslima/firebase-chat-sample

Comment: Yaa. But what else is required apart from firebase?

Comment: Thanks Narender . This is the exact thing which i was required. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: refer this it may helps you:https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I have done thing in one of the android app for sending push notification from our server. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a bit of research yourself on this and come back with any specific technical questions you have. You're getting down voted because your question is too general.

If you get stuck somewhere, make a new question asking for help on that particular problem. For example, if you couldn't get any response from the Node.js server in your Android app, post a question "No response from Node.js server using Socket.io" and give details. You'll get help in no time.

Search for "making a chat app android" and that should get you started.

Comment: Okay. I'll do some research and then i'll come here. Thank You.

Comment: Actually, i have tried to build a chat app using Node JS, Socket.io and MySql but i got stuck at somewhere. That's why i asked to start from scratch with new technologies. Thank You

Comment: Updated my answer to address this ^